# How to store variables from loop to a file

Tags: arrays, shell, loops, append

I am trying to store the variables $d, $tf_name, $db_orig created in the following loop to a file.I want to end up with a tab separated MY_FILE.txt containing the following fields $d, $tf_name, $db_orig and each iteration of this set of variables to be stored in a new line in the file MY_FILE.txt.

```
MY_ARRAY=() 
for d in */
   do

   IN=$d
   folderIN=(${IN//_/ })
   tf_name=${folderIN[-1]%/*}
   db_orig=${folderIN[-2]%/*};

ENTRY="$d\t$tf\t$id\t$db_orig\n"
MY_ARRAY+=$ENTRY

done

$MY_ARRAY > MY_FILE.txt
```

It doesn't recognise  \t and  \n as TAB and NEWLINE respectively. It stores all the values next to each other in the same line without TAB, in the array MY_ARRAY.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this happens because `$MY_ARRAY > MY_FILE.txt` is not a valid command.

You need to print your array to the file.

And in order to print it correctly you need either to use
`echo -e "${MY_ARRAY[@]}" >file`  or `printf`

By man echo

```
echo -e : enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

Moreover, if you need to store the $ENTRY to your array you need to do it like this:

```
MY_ARRAY+=("$ENTRY")
```

In any case, you can do it without the need of an array. You can just apply += in the ENTRY : `ENTRY+="$d\t$tf\t$id\t$db_orig\n"`

Test:

```
$ e+="a\tb\tc\td\n"
$ e+="aa\tbb\tcc\tdd\n"
$ e+="aaa\tbbb\tccc\tddd\n"
$ echo -e "$e"
a       b       c       d
aa      bb      cc      dd
aaa     bbb     ccc     ddd

# Test with array
$ e="a\tb\tc\td\n" && myar+=("$e")
$ e="aa\tbb\tcc\tdd\n" && myar+=("$e")
$ e="aaa\tbbb\tccc\tddd\n" && myar+=("$e")
$ echo -e "${myar[@]}"
a       b       c       d
 aa     bb      cc      dd
 aaa    bbb     ccc     ddd

#Alternative array printing
$ for i in "${myar[@]}";do echo -en "$i";done
a       b       c       d
aa      bb      cc      dd
```

Comment: @elpavlos Updated again. You can avoid the use of the array if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Georgios. Problem solved, file created!

Comment: Another question just came up. In some cases some of the variables don't exist. Let's say for the 3rd iteration $db_orig has no value. Would it be possible to create the 3rd line in the file ($d, $tf, $id) and have NA or just blank at this specific field $db_orig? In my script there is no entry at all for such cases.

Comment: @elpavlos Can be solved with clasic bash approach (see man bash). Test1 : `d="something" && echo "${d:-"NA"}"` --> prints something. Test 2: `d="" && echo "${d:-"NA"}"`  --> prints NA